# Prevent strtotime being encoded as string by json_encode

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am building data for a status dashboard that uses Highcharts.js, and loading it with ajax, however when using json_encode my timestamps are getting quoted, which means Highcharts chokes on them.

The code is:

```
$responseData = array();
foreach ($monitors as $monitor => $data) {
    foreach (array_reverse($data['responsetime']) as $responsetime) :
        $responses[] = array(strtotime($responsetime['datetime'])*1000 => $responsetime["value"]);
    endforeach;
    $responseData[] = array('name' => $data['friendlyname'], 'data' => $responses);
}
$responseData = json_encode($responseData,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK prevents problems with the value, but the key (a timestamp) gets quoted still.

Example output:

```
[{"name":"Series 1","data":[{"1432933860":1622},{"1432935660":1458},{"1432937461":1388}]},{"name":"Series 2","data":[{"1432933860":1622},{"1432935660":1458},{"1432937461":1388}]}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{"name":"Series 1","data":[{1432933860:1622},{1432935660:1458},{1432937461:1388}]},{"name":"Series 2","data":[{1432933860:1622},{1432935660:1458},{1432937461:1388}]}]
```

What am I doing wrong? Are keys always quoted perhaps?? Any way around this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, your desired output doesn't fit Highcharts requirements. I hope you are aware of that? For Highcharts should be: `"data":[[1432933860, 1622],  ... ]`, not `"data":[{1432933860:1622}, ... ]`.

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus - you right. I'll check whether that was a typo or another error, but unfortunately it doesn't get around the quote problem.

Comment: Your "example output" is very proper. In JS terms, or rather JSON terms, each name-property should be double-quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://json.org/

**From Objects**

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members). A name is a string.

**and from Strings**

> A string begins and ends with quotation marks.

So I would say that according to the standard: yes, you should always quote the key. Maby you could try to escape that key in javascript? Store them in a value and remove all non-numeric characters?

Something like:

```
myJsonKey = myJsonKey.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: Thanks @joey - not the answer I was hoping for but it stops me wasting any more time! 
I'll have to pass the data as JSON but then probably parse it to rebuild the array without quotes.